# Get data from software without API

Tags: api, methods

I want to get some data from a software, those data are displayed by the software.

My problems are: they don't provide a API and I can't sniff the software (cryptographed) 
 So, is there a way I can still get it (some methods)?

edit: it's a proprietary software who doesn't want to share/sell their API, and I need those data in other way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty dubious question, but possibly with innocent intention.

You are looking at trying to do screen-scraping: effectively taking a picture of the screen, then doing OCR (or similar) on what's in the picture, then working which of those optically-character-recognized text items are useful for your purposes, and then inserting them into your program's variables.

Bottom line: this is by no means easy. Getting access to the "real" data is going to be 100x quicker and more accurate.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I did thought in something like this, but didn't know the name of the technique